# How to dynamically add options to <select> list in CKeditor dialog

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am building a CKEditor plugin for Drupal 8. Currently it adds a toolbar button which triggers a modal dialog containing a select list with a few options. I've hardcoded the options in `plugin.js`, and everything works as expected. But those options must actually be dynamically added with php.

This is my plugin dialog definition, as per http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select with hardcoded options.

This goes in the `plugin.js` file loaded via `CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile()` in my plugin class:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('pluginDialog', function(editor) {
  return {
    title: 'Available options',
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 200,
    resizable: CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_BOTH,
    setup: function(e) {},
    commit: function(e) {},

    contents: [{
      id: 'tab-options',
      elements: [{
        type: 'select',
        id: 'select-options',
        label: 'Select an option:',
        items: [
          ['Option 1', '<span>Option 1</span>'],
          ['Option 2', '<span>Option 2</span>'],
          ['Option 3', '<span>Option 3</span>'],
          ['Option 4', '<span>Option 4</span>']
        ]
      }]
    }]
  };
});
```

`CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.contents.elements.items[]` have to be built from PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data to ckeditor via the `getConfig` method in your plugin, e.g.:

```
public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
  return [
    'pluginName_options' => $this->buildOptions()
  ];
}
```

And in the JS:

```
items: editor.config.pluginName_options
```